# Illegal/unsupported escape sequence when using regex in Android Studio

Tags: regex, android-studio

I'm trying to clean up text fetched from Wikipedia via the API. I want to remove the words 'Template:sfn' but I'm having trouble doing that with regular expression:

The text is something like:
...a private boarding school, after his parents discovered that he had made frequent trips into Manhattan without their permission.**Template:sfn**

With the help of: https://regex101.com I found out that my regexp needs to be something like: `\Template:.*\s`

If I copy and paste that to Android studio:

```
plainStr = plainStr.replaceAll("\\Template:.*\\s", "");
```

It tells me the two backslashes are not correct (**illegal/unsupported escape sequence**)

How do I rewrite my expression so AS accepts it?

And on top of that I want to remove all words after the colon. Wikipedia sometimes has Template:Nowrap, Template:Main, etc. That's my 'output' if I use the Bliki library (ConvertWikiToHtml) I want to remove all combinations. To make it more complex it could also be more than one word like:Template:dead link or Template:cite press release but I don't think this can be handled with a regex.

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: You don't have to escape `T`. Try removing it.  Also `Template:sfn` or `Template:\S*` is better than your present regex.

Comment: @Rahul: You ***must not*** escape `T`.

Comment: @Rahul: that won't remove a whitespace at the end; that is different, but it is not clear to me that it is better.

Comment: @ysth: OP wishes to remove literal `Template:sfn` why complicate it with `dot` and `whitespaces`.

Comment: @Rahul are you certain they do not want the whitespace removed?  I am not.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me out! I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear.
As a matter of fact I want to remove all words after the colon. Wikipedia sometimes has Template:Nowrap, Template:Main, etc. That's my 'output' if I use the Bliki library (ConvertWikiToHtml) I want to remove all combinations. To make it more complex it could also be more than one word like:Template:dead link or Template:cite press release but I don't think this can be handled with a regex.

Comment: @MikeDole: Add that information to your question as it already caused some confusion here. You have to figure out a pattern or character that marks the end of what you wish to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken; a backslash before the T accomplishes nothing.

Just remove it:

```
plainStr = plainStr.replaceAll("Template:.*\\s", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was Android Studio issue. At least I couldn't explain it otherwise because the code below was compiled and ran well in Eclipse:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\R|.+\\z");
```

However after I copied it and pasted in Android Studio `\\R` was underlined with the error message "illegal/unsupported escape sequence". However the code was compiled and executed without any problems.